# AJAX not working on IE and EDGE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I made an application using ajax in some points, and I figured out that it wasn't working on IE and EDGE.
On the examples bellow, I'm trying to generate a PDF from one html page.
Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  try {
  var url_string = window.location.href;
  var url = new URL(url_string);
  var token = url.searchParams.get("token");

  if (url_string.includes('/quiz/show_report')) {
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      url: '/chart.js?token=' + token
    });
  }
 } catch (e) {}
});
```

on the document, I'm calling

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: '/download_pdf?token=' + token,
  data: {
    natural_chart: $('#natural-chart').attr('data-image'),
    humanities_chart: $('#humanities-chart').attr('data-image'),
    language_codes_chart: $('#language-codes-chart').attr('data-image'),
    mathematics_technology_chart: $('#mathematics-technology-chart').attr('data-image')
  }
}).success(function(e) {
  window.location = '/download?token=' + token;
});
```

What I tryed:
Using cache false
Forcing ie compatibility mode with that metatag:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`

and that:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >`

and all that other compatible meta tags. I Tryed also that ones

`<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Cache-Control">`
`<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma">`

We updated the jquery version to the newer one (3.2.1),

Anyone has any idea what I might do to fix it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hmm.. I think this problem is same of mine maybe. Are you testing this in local host??

Comment: I just tested on staging.
Aparently it's a problem with ajax and iframes. Are you using iframe too?

Comment: Someone recommended that but I didn't try that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747418/with-angularjs-http-post-return-response-error-in-microsoft-edge This post is my question that is similar with your problem. Very soon, I'll test it not in local, so I expect can get result whether my conclusion is right or not.

Comment: I tested this problem on local, on staging and on production and it didn't worked ):

Comment: Really?? Then this is a big problem to me.. I'll try to find another solution and if I got one which works well, I'll share that with you.

Comment: I brought several suggested solutions. Some of these might you've already seen but I hope one of these can help you. 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547227/angular-js-post-request-not-sending-json-data    2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463284/angulars-http-post-not-working-in-ms-edge  3.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581503/microsoft-edge-blocked-cross-domain-requests-sent-to-ips-in-same-private-network  4.  https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/angularjs/interacting-with-apis-using-http-angularjs/

Comment: And also I've found a weird action in edge. I've used `$http()` method in my project and this is never send request to server. I don't know why but after I changed function like `$http.post()`, then send something but couldn't get correct response from server. This is all I've gotten

Comment: I'll try that! 
But we decided to drop the funcionality that needed ajax on IE and edge

Comment: LOL sadly, we also reached same conclusion of yours. Maybe this might be a bug in MS browsers. Good luck to you. :)

Comment: @RachelCurioso I'm having the same problem, did you ever find a solution to this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any information about why it can not work at EDGE? As I know, EDGE did not support "searchParams" right now.

Comment: I don't know ):
All that I know is that we have anotter application that AJAX work fine with EDGE, So, I don't have a clue ):